# youtube-dl ytsearch: only searches for first word

Tags: youtube-dl

When I do "ytsearch: pray for rain", It only searches up the first word, so, pray. I need to to search for "Pray for rain" instead of "Pray".

Comment: Please example what are you trying to achieve? show what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Put a quotation mark around the beggining of "ytsearch"

For example

youtube_dl "ytsearch:[your searched sentence]"
:)